# Token to get the last component of [node:url]

Tags: 8, tokens

I'm using `[node:url:relative]` but my path has multiple parts `/content-type/node-title` . I would like to get only the `node-title` part.

Alternatively, a token that give me the node title transliterate would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`[node:title]` will give you the node title.